# Pixel 2 XL will not charge anymore

Tags: charging

Does anybody know what this weird symbol on my pixel 2 XL is? This appeared for the first time when I plug it in, when I unplug it there's a great big X on that symbol I've had this phone for a very long time never ever seen that before also,it says that it's rapidly charging and guess what, it's not deader than a doornail and I can't turn it on so I can't transfer any of my information on to  another phone, I have all so cleaned charging port  still nothing, (cleaning of Port was done with non conductive material no metals.)

I managed to turn it on for about 3 minutes, I had to continually hold down the power button, battery icon did have the charging symbol , indicating that it was charging, but still nothing and that was many hours ago. but then it turned off again. it's obviously registering that it's plugged in, because when I unplug it that symbols the X on it, so how do I go about transferring my info from the pixel 2XL to a new phone? If it's not charging and it won't turn on?? does anybody have any advice for me g

[image: 1]

Comment: I see two possibilities: 1. the battery is near to death or 2. the charging port is partially broken. Both are common problems for an often used older phone. But if the battery is bad usually the phone works normally when connected to a charger. As your case is different my guess would be the charging port. If the soldering point break or get loose it can happen that the phone still recognizes if it is connected to the charger but if it tries to draw power this does not work because of the port.